# Steps to install MS Access 2016 Database at client's computers?

Tags: ms-access, runtime, ms-access-2016

I have a MS Access 2016 databases where the tables are back end and all other objects are front end. I'd like to save and install the database on few of client's computers for their use (executable or something like this.)

The client does not have MS Access. they are now installing Office365.

if someone can assist in the step by step on how to:
- Save my database in a none editable format (ACCDE I think!!!)
- Install at the client's computers.
- Best practice for the on going update and tweaking.

- Do I need to install Runtime2013(MSI) on my computer as well or only on Client computer or only on Client's computer?

Note: if I am thinking in a completely wrong direction I would appreciate if you can note this in your answer.

I've been reading a lot about Runtime2013(MSI) and Runtime2016, etc. I am just lost how to do this stage of my project.

I have a feeling this question has been answered many times and many thank you to all  your support.

Comment: Runtime needs to be installed on computers that do not have full Access installed. You might want to have a computer set up with the Runtime to test. Your question is too broad for SO and any answers would be opinions.

Comment: There are many editions of Office365 - most of them include Access. Check which they have.

Answer (score 0):

The process is quite simple. You need to install the runtime on each of those computers. However, since they are using office 365, then the 2016 runtime will NOT install (since there is a not a click to run 2016 runtime – you need this). They have announced a CTR version of the runtime, but until it is released, then you have to install the 2013 runtime.

What this means, you REALLY (but really really really really) have to develop your application with Access 2013. (You can’t success develop with a different version).

This also means you need to ensure you application provides all the forms and menus to “use” the application, since the basic Access UI you get as a developer and user will NOT be available.

You can “test” your application in runtime mode by using a shortcut with the /runtime switch, or you can re-name the accDE to an accDR and launch that. So at the end of the day, you need and want to deploy an accDE.

So you simply install the 2013 runtime on each workstation. At that point, you then place the accDE on each workstation. You might want to cook up some kind of installer to create a shortcut on the user’s desktop, and the folder where you place the accDE needs to be set as a trusted location (this is a registry entry – thus I suggest using one of many free installers to setup the shortcut and make these settings. Such an installer could get fancy and also install the runtime if you wish (so how much effort you put into your installer is really up to you). In a pinch, just install the runtime on each computer. Then setup a folder for the accDE – and possible a shortcut on the desktop – and as noted you have to set the trusted location.